# Change PATH for global command gs from /usr/bin/gs to /usr/local/bin/gs

Tags: bash, ubuntu, .profile

I need to change my PATH on ubuntu server for this command: **gs**

Now it looks here **/usr/bin/gs** but I need it to look here instead **/usr/local/bin/gs**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have two different versions of gs installed. Couple of options depending on what you want to do:

Run the gs with full path

`/usr/local/bin/gs`

or

add `/usr/local/bin/` before `/usr/bin/` in PATH variable.

Something like

`PATH="/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"`

> Note: You can put this in profile settings as well. If you do this, all scripts that you run will be effected.

Comment: thank you!  I only have one version installed on /usr/local/bin/gs. But when I run like gs -version it can't find it because it looks here /usr/bin/gs

Comment: do 
`type -all gs`.
and 
`echo "$PATH"`

Ok. It means /usr/local/bin is not present in your path.

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/bin/:$PATH" thsi did it